# What is the best way to draw cluster for every station?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, cluster-analysis

I have a binary matrix "X" of U rows and N columns. Each row of X has 1 to maximum 3 ones. Each row corresponds to a subscriber and every column corresponds to a service point. So, the ones in a given row corresponds to the service points that the subscriber can be served by.

How can I graphically show this association?

Lets say, we have 5 service points, randomly/systematically arranged over an area.

x-coordinates of the service points are `{200, 600, 200, 600, 400}`

y-coordinates of the service points are `{200, 200, 600, 600, 400}`

And we have 10 subscribers randomly distributed over the area with boundary points (0, 0), (0, 800), (800, 0) and (800, 800).

And the X matrix is given by

```
X = {{0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
     {1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
     {1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1}};
```

How to graphically show this connections?

Lets say, we call the set of service points associated with given users a clusters. So, different subscribers will have different clusters. I just want to see the relationship of different clusters for different users, for example, if  two nearby subscribers have the same cluster or they have different clusters?

Comment: Start by at least representing your matrices in Mathematica code, i.e. as nested lists. Then, are you looking to generate a graph output? Or some kind of plot?

Comment: @MarcoB, I prefer graph output. Plots are also welcome.

Comment: I am not sure that this is a Mathematica question yet. You should tell us how you want the relationship represented, and then somebody can help you construct the graph you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `IGraphM` you can use the function `IGBipartiteIncidenceGraph` using your matrix `X` input:

```
<< IGraphM`

subscribers = "Subscriber" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[First@Dimensions[X]];

servicepoints = "ServicePoint" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[Last@Dimensions[X]];

IGBipartiteIncidenceGraph[{subscribers, servicepoints}, X, 
 GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> Dimensions[X]}, 
 VertexLabels -> {v : Alternatives @@ subscribers :> Placed["Name", Before], 
   v : Alternatives @@ servicepoints :> Placed["Name", After]},  
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 ImagePadding -> {{70, 70}, {10, 10}}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

If you don't have `IGraphM` you can construct an `AdjacencyMatrix` from your `X` and use [`AdjacencyGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AdjacencyGraph.html):

```
vl = Join[subscribers, servicepoints];

am = ArrayFlatten[{{0, X}, {Transpose[X], 0}}];

AdjacencyGraph[vl, am, 
 GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> Dimensions[X]}, 
 VertexLabels -> {v : Alternatives @@ subscribers :> 
    Placed["Name", Before], 
   v : Alternatives @@ servicepoints :> Placed["Name", After]},  
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ImagePadding -> {{70, 70}, {10, 10}}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Remove the option `GraphLayout` and use coordinates of your choice as `VertexCoordinates`:

```
xsp = {200, 600, 200, 600, 400};
ysp = {200, 200, 600, 600, 400};

SeedRandom[1]
locations = Join[Thread[servicepoints -> Transpose[{xsp, ysp}]], 
    Thread[subscribers -> RandomPoint[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {800, 800}], 10]]];

ag = AdjacencyGraph[vl, am, VertexCoordinates -> locations,
  VertexShapeFunction -> {v : Alternatives @@ servicepoints -> "Star"},
  VertexSize -> Large, 
  VertexLabels -> {v : Alternatives @@ subscribers :> 
     Placed["Name", Before], 
    v : Alternatives @@ servicepoints :> Placed["Name", After]},  
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ImagePadding -> {{70, 70}, {10, 10}}, 
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

We can also use [`CommunityGraphPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CommunityGraphPlot.html):

1. Using the default community structure:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[ag, 
 CommunityRegionStyle -> (Opacity[.3, #] & /@ RandomColor[10])]
```

[image]

Or, using the option `Method -> "Hierarchical"`:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[ag, 
 CommunityRegionStyle -> (Opacity[.3, #] & /@ RandomColor[10]), 
 Method -> "Hierarchical"]
```

[image]

The automatic community structure used above is:

```
FindGraphCommunities[ag] // Column
```

[image]

2. Defining a custom community structure such  that each subscriber `i` together with service points connected to `i` form a community (cluster):

```
communitystructure1 = Prepend[AdjacencyList[ag, #], #] & /@ subscribers;
Column @ communitystructure1
```

[image]

```
CommunityGraphPlot[ag, communitystructure1, 
 CommunityRegionStyle -> (Opacity[.3, #] & /@ RandomColor[10])]
```

[image]

2. Defining a custom community structure such  that each service point `j` together with subscribers connected to `j` form a community (cluster):

```
communitystructure2 = Prepend[AdjacencyList[ag, #], #] & /@ servicepoints;
Column @ communitystructure2
```

[image]

```
CommunityGraphPlot[ag, communitystructure2, 
 CommunityRegionStyle -> (Opacity[.3, #] & /@ RandomColor[10])]
```

[image]

Comment: would you please explain a bit the last two graphs. Also, why there are three different sets of subscribers (as we have three colors to distinguish the subscribers). In the last graph, we have 5 regions corresponding to 5 service points. Is it possible to have same color for the service points markers as their region

Comment: @dipaknarayanan, I added some explanation re how the example community structures are formed.